# how dompdf supports php7

Tags: dompdf, php-7

I used older version of dompdf in a project about 5 years ago. Now I just downloaded 0.8.0 (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases[link](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases)) version, and its release note says "Improves compatibility with PHP 7.1". But for demo usage, it has php5.x "use" style as "use Dompdf\Dompdf;" that throw error on PHP 7. What is appropriate method to use dompdf on php7?

Comment: The compatibility improvements were mainly around cleaning up the use of strings in numeric calculations. It's not clear what you mean by "it has php5.x use style". Can you clarify and provide more detail (including the errors you receive)?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_use_statement.htm

Comment: I use Netbeans and php7 coding, and it shows error on Netbeans, even before loading php. If I remove "use" line, it shows "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Dompdf' not found " , if I comment out "use" line, white screen.

Comment: That's not a PHP5-style `use` statement. The `use` statement syntax was expanded in PHP7 to allow additional functionality.

Comment: Anyway, "use Dompdf\Dompdf;" gave white screen on php7, and I initialized dompdf with "$dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf();" and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I changed those lines :

```
     // reference the Dompdf namespace
     use Dompdf\Dompdf;
 // instantiate and use the dompdf class
   $dompdf = new Dompdf();
```

to :

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf();
```

and now, it works on php7.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this problem from dompdf if your php version is 7.0 and your `dompdf_config.inc.php` file is exists.

```
if(class_exists('DOMPDF', false)) 
{ 
    return; 
}

PHP_VERSION >= 7.0 or die("DOMPDF requires PHP 7.0+");
```

Just change 7.0 to 5.6

```
PHP_VERSION >= 5.6 or die("DOMPDF requires PHP 7.0+");
```

It works fine for me, I hope this helps someone.